# firejail memory limit

Tags: ubuntu, firejail

I want to create a **firejail** profile that limits memory for applications.

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to limit memory using **firejail**.
But It seems that some versions had the `--rlimit-as` flag but I can't find it on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I managed to restrict memory with cgroup profile and use it with firejail. I still wonder why firejail does not allow this directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 has `firejail version 0.9.38.10`, and Ubuntu 18.04 has `firejail version 0.9.52`. See release notes: https://firejail.wordpress.com/download-2/release-notes/ they say, for `0.9.52` (amont other things)

> - feature: --rlimit-as

---

`firejail (0.9.56-LTS)` entry has

> - command line options removed:
>      ..., --rlimit*, ...

yet at the moment https://firejail.wordpress.com/features-3/man-firejail/ lists them.

The readme of `firejail` says about LTS "branch"

> We are rebasing our Long Term Support branch of Firejail. The current LTS version (0.9.38.x) is more than two years old. The new version updates the code base to 0.9.56. We target a reduction of approx. 40% of the code by removing rarely used features (chroot, overlay, rlimits, cgroups), incomplete features (private-bin, private-lib), and a lot of instrumentation (build profile feature, tracing, auditing, etc).

So you have to be careful which version you install!